# How do I show a mobile keyboard in react-web-app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**The following code is omitted a lot.**

```
const searchRef = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
    searchRef.current.focus();
  }, []);

<input
   type="text"
   className="search_bar"
   ref={searchRef}
/>
```

**I want the mobile keyboard to appear automatically when the screen appears.**

Comment: i think you should check this npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-simple-keyboard

Comment: Thank you for your help, but you should see a native keyboard.